# Git - make development and master track different repos. Sensible?

Tags: git, heroku, staging

I have a project which is in git and deploys to heroku.  The remote url is `git@heroku.com:myappname.git` and the .git/config looks like this:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = git@heroku.com:myappname.git
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

I just made a new heroku app called "myappname-staging" which i want to use as a staging site for this app.  I was thinking that i would set it up so that the "master" branch pushes to the production remote and the "development" branch pushes to the staging remote.  Is this the sensible/conventional way to handle this situation?

I can't quite figure out how to do this.  When i made the staging app on heroku it gave me this back:

```
Creating myappname-staging.... done
http://myappname-staging.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:myappname-staging.git
Git remote heroku added
```

And my config now looks like this:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = git@heroku.com:myappnamestef.git
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:myappname-staging.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[remote "staging"]
  url = git@heroku.com:myappname-staging.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
```

Can anyone set me straight?

thanks, max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:

```
[branch "development"]
  remote = staging
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

You can do that from the command line via:

```
$ git config branch.development.remote staging
$ git config branch.development.merge refs/heads/master
```

That will set up the `development` branch to tracking the `master` branch on staging.

Comment: Great, thanks mipadi!  Had a feeling it might be that but wanted to check before i went and mashed up our production app :)  cheers